# Java: run custom code on field access

Tags: java, annotations, field

my use-case is the following: I have a class with a member field, which is accessed by almost all of its methods. I would like to be able to run some custom code modifying the member field each time it is accessed so that the methods see the modified value. My initial idea was to use a custom annotation.

So basically I wanted to have something like this:

```
  Class myClass {
    ...
    @MyAnnotation
    MyFieldType myField;
    ...

    public void myMethod()
    {
       ...
       Something smth = myField.getSomething();
       ...
    }
  }
```

such that when I run the method myMethod() (or any other class method), some code is executed before that modifying myField:

```
void MyAnnotationProcessor()
{
  ...
  myField.change();
}
```

so that when I access myField in myMethod, I see the changed myField and not the one which was before the method call. Basically, in this aspect, @MyAnnotation should be something like @Before in junit.

I tried to implement @MyAnnotation as a custom constraint, but, unfortunately, it did not work as planned, the constraint validator was never called when methods accessed the field.

Is there any way to do this with annotations? Or am I fighting an already lost struggle?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I have solved my problem in an entirely different way, without having to intercept field access. Big thanks to all who commented.

Comment: so why don`t you go with the simple solution, use access methods in your case  getMyField() and in your access method, modify myField  before passing it on.

Comment: The thing is that the field is in the class itself, so another developer may just as well access the field itself, instead of the getter. If I implement the needed changes in the getter, I will have to every once in a while remind other developers working on this code not to access the field directly, but via a getter.

Comment: (1) write a getter and a setter. (2) rename the field, and make it `private`. (3) Replace every code line that breaks with a call to the getter or the setter.  (4) hang your custom code on the getter and the setter.  (Extra credit) Implement the "Observer" pattern.